# simple_html_dom. Текст без тегов, php

Tags: php, парсер, simple-html-dom

Добрый день! Имеется `html` страница, заполненная содержанием следующего вида:

```
<a name="00:00:00" href="#00:00:00" class="ts">[00:00:00]</a>
<span class="mn">&lt;Nick&gt;</span>
" Шаблон "
<br>
```

Используя `simple_html_dom`, необходимо проверить всю страницу и отыскать совпадение с фильтром.

```
foreach($html->find('a.ts, span.mn, text') as $body => $value)
    {
        $iText = "Шаблон";
        if (strpos($value, $iText) !== false)
        {
            echo "Find it.";
            echo $value."<br>Nick: ";
            echo $value->find('span')->plaintext."<br>";

        }  
    }
```

В данном примере кода отображается найденный текст по шаблону. Мне необходимо захватить помимо текста еще и `<span>` с ником, и `<а>` с датой. Буду благодарна за подсказку, как правильно это сделать! Спасибо большое!

Comment: Подобные блоки у вас  на странице повторяются? Если да, то есть ли у них родительский. Если да, то ищите все родительские, и проверяйте текст внутри по шаблону. Если подходит, то ищите в блоке нужный контент.

Comment: @teran, блоки повторяются, 90% всей страницы. Родительского блока нет, все в <body>. Поэтому и возник такой вопрос. То есть, отдельно выцепить текст получается, а уже связать его с предыдущими, например, тегами - нет. Буду рада помощи и спасибо!

Comment: тогда, наверное, проще взять исходный текст, и вручную разделить его на блоки. А с ними уже работать потом.

Comment: @teran, то есть, силами либы такого не вытворить, да? Парсить самому через регулярки?

Comment: можете попробовать искать только `text`, а когда найдете подходящий, то через `prev_sibling` найти соответствующие `a` и  `span`.

Comment: @teran, спасибо за подсказку! Почитала о prev_sibling и вот... Не могли бы Вы мне, если Вам не сложно, показать хотя бы маленький пример работы метода со схожим контекстом? Просто в переменную занести `$body->prev_sibling();`, чтобы потом подхватывать теги, стоящие до текста, да?

Comment: @teran, к сожалению, `prev_sibling()` подхватывает последний див на странице, который идет после всех текстовых блоков:(